# artefacts in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser

From some moment I had view artefacts in Chrome browser on every site, like this:
[image]
in Safari everything looks fine. 
What it might be?

Comment: Restart your machine and re-check.

Comment: You mean reboot computer? Already did. Nothing changed